# System.Reflection.MethodInfo class is abstract then why it has a protected constructor?

Tags: c#

Abstract class and interfaces cannot be instantiated.Then why System.Reflection.MethodInfo has a protected constructor of its own .Please explain?

Comment: because if you inherit from them you can call it's protected constructor with base()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making an abstract class' constructor `protected` is a fairly common pattern. The intention is to guide programmers towards the intended use of the class/constructor:

1. It hides the constructor (e.g. from Intellisense) in cases where one is attempting to instantiate the class (which would not be possible with an abstract class), so you get an additional hint that the class cannot be instantiated.

   From the Framework Design Guidelines, chapter 4.4 "Abstract class design":

   > *"Constructors should be public only if users will need to create instances of the type. Because you cannot create instances of an abstract type, an abstract type with a public constructor is incorrectly designed and misleading to the users."*
2. At the same time the constructor is still available for subclasses (as could be seen e.g. in Visual Studio's Object Explorer or in some other form of reference documentation), hinting at the fact that the type is *meant* to be used that way (subclassed).